# Increasing counter in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have field called ads_counter in my database, and I need to increase its value each time when this ad is rendered.

I tried to write a custom method and use it in the controller responsible for this data, but that didn't work. Are there any built-in methods to increase the value of a field in the database?

Comment: If you share your structure we may help you with more information! Thank you!

Comment: Already found another way, using update_attributes.Thanks

Comment: The best way to do it is calling increment since update_attributes call validations and stuff. The increment comand does exactly and exclusivelly what you asked for.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is the `increment` method that you can call in your ActiveRecord.

For reference: [increment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment)

**Edit:**

To make it save directly use the `increment!`

You may use it this way:

```
instance.increment!(:ads_counter)
```

It automatically increments by 1

```
instance.increment!(:ads_counter, <number>)
```

It increments by number provided

Comment: Great, full answer: reverence to docs + real example + little more about + nice formatted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have the method [`increment!`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment!) that increments an attribute and saves the record

```
your_object.increment!(:ads_counter)
```

Put this code in the `show` method of your controller.

Comment: this method increment only by 1, or there are additional params ?

Comment: You can use `your_object.increment!(:ads_counter, 42)` ; There's a link to the doc of the method in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try [increment!](https://railsguide.org/rails/ActiveRecord::Callbacks/increment!) method

```
object.increment!(:method_name)
```

Comment: Please provide details answer. Thanks